# "I'm not going to have..." vs. "I'm going not to have..." vs. "I'm going to not have"

Tags: verbs, negation

Is there a rule that governs when you change around the placement of "not" in a sentence relative to the verb? For example:

> I'm NOT going to Spain to have fun.

or

> I'm going, NOT to have fun, but to look for work.

or

> I'm going to NOT have fun and study instead.

Comment: After the `I'm going` in the second sentence, I believe you need a comma.

Comment: I think this question should migrate to ELL, maybe?

Answer (score 1):

In standard Modern English, negation is achieved by adding *not* after an auxiliary verb. If no such verb is present then the dummy auxiliary *do (does, did)* is introduced. For example:

> I have gone → I have not gone (have is the auxiliary)
>   He goes → He does not go (no auxiliary in the original sentence)

Different rules apply in subjunctive, imperative and non-finite clauses.

So, here in your question, only the first sentence is correct, the second can be fine, depending on what you mean (but without the comma), and the third is incorrect.

> I'm NOT going to Spain to have fun.

The correct form for the second sentence:

> I'm going not to have fun, but to look for a job.

or with a slightly different meaning:

> I'm not going to have fun, but to look for a job.

And the correct form for the third sentence:

> I'm not going to have fun, but study instead.

or

> I'm going not to have fun, but study instead.

You can keep this in your mind that *not* must always appear *after the auxiliary* and *before the main verb*.

See the [Wikipedia article about negation in English](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_grammar#Negation) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for your input. How would you use a split infinitive in the 3rd sentence? I think split infinitives is really what my student is trying to understand.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with his second sentence.  Upon what basis do you judge it as ungrammatical?

Comment: All three of these sentences are perfectly grammatical. Some are more marked than other, which means that we would use them in special circumstances, or to achieve a specific effect. However, it's definitely wrong to say that they're ungrammatical!!!

Comment: @guifa Thanks for your comment. I had misread the second sentence. Updating the answer. (:

Comment: "You could always go out and have some fun ..." "No, I'm going to *not* have fun and study instead."